# Where to get lists of kaomoji (Japanese emoticons)?

Tags: data-request, text, japan, japanese

Where can I find a downloadable database of Japanese-style emoticons (顔文字, kaomoji, "face characters")? The database should ideally be free.

Examples of kaomoji are: `{^.^}`, `(°Д°)`, `(◕‿◕)`.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but still relevant for others. I've found two good datasets at this point, both labeled:

1. https://github.com/topics/kaomoji-emoticons
2. https://github.com/elisa-aleman/Kaomoji_parsing/blob/master/Kaomoji.csv